# Open admin page depending on the value of a php session

Tags: php, session

I am creating a website and I want to know if it is safe to depend on the value of a session to allow access to the admin page or not

```
if($_SESSION["allowAdmin"]=="yes"){//load admin page}
```

I wonder if any hacker can create that session and thus gain access to the administration site